# Showing a custom view on entire project as a footer

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, footer

My project architecture is a 'Master Detail' and i want to show a footer through out all the viewcontrollers or tableviewcontrollers that i navigate.

Please help me to find the way.

Comment: you can add your footer to window as subview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add it this way and instead of UIView use your customView's object to achieve your goal.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.navMain = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navMain;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    UIView *viewFooter = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 431, 320, 49)];
    [viewFooter setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self.window addSubview:viewFooter];
    [self.window bringSubviewToFront:viewFooter];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: thanks eptdeveloper, worked for me, but i tried the code block in the ViewController's didLoad method...

probably this is because of storyboard [forget to mention that :(]

Comment: @Batman4Ever : Doesn't matter if you achieved your final output any how :) if you need further help you're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the custom view to the `window` as a subview. It will display in all screens of the project as a footer. **It'll work perfectly unless your application support orientation.**

Comment: here what i did but not working...

'_addView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.window.frame.size.height - VIEWHEIGHT, 320, VIEWHEIGHT)];
    [self.window addSubview:_addView];
    [_addView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];'

Comment: @Batman4Ever : try out my code it may help you.

Comment: @Batman4Ever here i think you have to add [self.window bringSubviewToFront:_addView];

Comment: i have already tried in that way but not worked, i think this is because of storyboard :( the code snippet is moved to Viewcontroller's viewDidLoad method and it worked. thanks RamsChowdury for your help

Answer (score 0):

You have to use one root controller with footer, and content view. Add other view controllers as child of root view controller and views as subview of the content view.

I wrote a post about it, you can find it here:http://antrix1989.blogspot.com/2013/09/uiviewcontroller-as-singleton.html